# How to rasterize a 3d mesh?

Tags: 3d, mesh, rasterizing

I have a 3d mesh (a set of triangles) that defines a closed watertight surface. I want to rasterize this mesh, that is divide the space occupied by the mesh to even, little cubes (the 3d equivalent of 2d pixels), and paint the cubes that a triangle passes through as black and the rest as white. Similar to how one would rasterize a 2d vector-graphic image into a rasterized bmp, for instance. 
In other words, I want to output a 3d array, `A` that is `M x M x M`, such that `A(i,j,k)` is 1 if there is some triangle which passes through the space occupied by the cube at the location `i,j,k`.
Hope that was clear, if not - tell me and I'll clarify.

Any algorithm, library, matlab routine will do.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this voxelizer](http://techhouse.org/~dmorris/projects/voxelizer/) quite fitting for my needs. It works quite fast, and also has a matlab script for reading the resulting voxel file into matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot present you some algorithm or library, but a small hint. The term you are looking for is **Voxelization**. Try google and it may present you some ressources on this, along with this small but also quite old [introduction](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~vislab/projects/volume/Papers/Voxel/index.html) to the topic which might be a foundation for further research.